# Javascript objects with number property in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, instance-variables, javascript-objects

Can anybody help me understand why the "counter" property seems to get reset on every new instance?  I expected it to work like the "letters" property, which is shared across all instantiated objects.

I came across this while putting together some sample code as to why prototype properties **shouldn't** be used this way unless they are intended to be static.

Sample Code:

```
var Dog = function() {
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
Dog.prototype = {
    counter : 2,
    letters : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
    initialize : function(dogName) {
        this.dogName = dogName;
    },
    add : function(amount) {
        this.counter += amount;
    },
    arr : function(char) {
        this.letters.push(char);
    }
};

var fido = new Dog("fido");
fido.add(1);
fido.arr('d');
console.log(fido.counter); // 3, as expected
console.log(fido.letters.toString()); // ABCD, as expected

var maxx = new Dog("maxx");
maxx.add(1);
maxx.arr('e');
console.log(maxx.counter); // 3, Unexpected, Why isn't this 4?
console.log(maxx.letters.toString()); // ABCDE, as expected
```

Comment: Because your line `this.counter += amount` is actually doing `this.counter = Dog.Prototype.counter + 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the line

```
this.counter += amount;
```

What happens? `this.counter` doesn't find property *counter* on the instance, so it takes it from the *prototype*, but when it comes to setting, it sets it on the instance

```
var fido = new Dog("fido");
console.log(fido.hasOwnProperty('counter')); // false
fido.add(1);
console.log(fido.hasOwnProperty('counter')); // true
```

Remember it is shorthand for

```
this.counter = this.counter + amount;
/*    ↑              ↑
   instance          |
                 prototype */
```

---

As for *letters*, that is working as expected because `push` is happening on the *Object* in the prototype - you're not setting a new instance variable. If you were setting an instance variable, it may still work because *Objects* are assigned to variables by reference, i.e.

```
var a = {}, b = a;
b.foo = 'bar';
a.foo; // "bar";
```

Comment: Good answer; you should speak to why the array `letters` remains shared across instances of `Dog`.

Comment: @NickHusher I've edited in an explanation for _letters_ too, as requested. Though I don't feel there is too much to say about it, as the action performed is entirely different.

Comment: Thank you Paul! I suspected the instance vs. prototype scope on the counter but the array was throwing me off. I didn't think about the fact that I'm calling a function on the array vs setting it directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `this.counter += amount` in `add`, `this` refers to the object that `add` was called on (in this case fido or maxx).  In this case the += operator reads from the inherited value because there is no local value for `counter` and the writes to a new local value.  Because fido or maxx now have their own counter properties the prototype covered up.  Try the following:

```
Dog.prototype = {

    ...

    add : function(amount) {
        Dog.prototype.counter += amount;
    },

    ...

};
```